# How to call controller method and pass the object from ajax call in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am in a learning process and working on ASP.net MVC 5 project. So, I have a model view which has other model views in it.

**Parent Model View**

```
public class FullConfigMV
{
 some properties here
 public ElementStyleMV Page { get; set; }
}
```

Now below is what I want to achieve.

1. Make an ajax call
2. once the ajax call hits the controller function set some values
3. now from there I need to pass that object to another controller action which will return it's view.

Step 1.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#tan").change(function()
        {
            alert(this.value);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Settings/GetAvailableLocationsFor',
                data: { accountId: 28462, groupId: 35},
                success: function (data) {
                    //Whatever
                },
                error: function () {
                    DisplayError('Failed to load the data.');
                }
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

After step 1 my breakpoint hits at

```
public ActionResult GetAvailableLocationsFor(int accountId, int groupId)
        {
            FullConfigMV configData = SetLoader.GetDSettings(accountId, groupId);
            Utils.SiteCss = configData.CssStyles();
           // NOW AT THIS PLACE I WANT TO CALL ANOTHER CONTROLLER FUNCTION
           // AND PASS THE `configData Obj`
            return View();
        }
```

I know we have something like

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

BUT HOW TO PASS THE `config Obj`

The controller function that I want to call is in
 `Home Controller` and the action name is `Index`

```
public ActionResult Index(FullConfigMV data)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

If the requirement seems weird then kindly bear/humor me on this.

**EDIT**

After the solution suggested "use `TempData` " But the problem is I have two index action in my controller. I want the `SECOND` Index Action to get hit. But the first one is getting hit.

**First:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

**Second**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FullConfigMV data)
{
}
```

Code used is

```
    public ActionResult GetAvailableLocationsFor(int accountId, int groupId)
    {
        FullConfigMV configData = SetLoader.GetDSettings(accountId, groupId);
        SimUtils.SiteCss = configData.CssStyles();
        TempData["config"] = configData;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: To pass objects between `RedirectToAction` calls you use Session or TempData. If you just need the (non-view) result from the other controller action -- you move that code into a new class so that any controller can get the result.

Comment: Please don't use every version tag in your question. You've said you're using version 5; use that version tag. I've edited it for you this time.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan : Thanks. I will take care of it from next time.

Comment: Does your `GetAvailableLocations` have a view, or is it used to process data?

Comment: It does  not need a view. Just to process data.

Comment: Why can't you just use route values for this? `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new { data = configData}); `? Will that work?

Comment: I am just a beginner. Where shall I put this code.

Comment: Also, Can I get the object data in the ajax success call from first action call and then again call the ajax call on "Index" action with the data I received. That will be perfect for me.

Comment: You cannot use `RedirectToAction()` to navigate to a POST method (and ajax calls never redirect anyway - the whole of point of ajax is to stay on the same page. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: After all the inputs I got I have rethought and I have put a new question altogether. Because this one seems to be invalid design. My new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706791/how-to-call-nested-ajax-call-and-send-object-data-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: I am beginner and can sometime think of silly design. bear with me.

Comment: @StephenMuecke BviLLe_Kid : I have put another design. See if that makes a little sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using TempData. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx:

"A typical use for a TempDataDictionary object is to pass data from an action method when it redirects to another action method."

There's plenty of documentation out there but simply use

```
TempData["config"] = configData;
```

In your first actionresult, and retrieve it in your Home> Index with

```
var configData = TempData["config"] as FullConfigMV;
```

Comment: And then how should I call the Index of homecontroller. `return redirectoaction("Index", "home")`?

Comment: Yes, that will work with TempData, it keeps it for the current and next request.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on this, but you *might* be able to pass that as a route.. if not then use `TempData`.

Example:

```
public ActionResult GetAvailableLocationsFor(int accountId, int groupId)
{
    FullConfigMV configData = SetLoader.GetDSettings(accountId, groupId);
    Utils.SiteCss = configData.CssStyles();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new { data = configData});
}
```

Or if above doesn't work:

```
public ActionResult GetAvailableLocationsFor(int accountId, int groupId)
{
    FullConfigMV configData = SetLoader.GetDSettings(accountId, groupId);
    Utils.SiteCss = configData.CssStyles();
    TempData["config"] = configData;
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}

// Index ActionResult

public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (TempData["config"] != null)
    {
        FullConfigMV variableName = (FullConfigMV)TempData["config"];
        ...
        return View(/*whatever you want here*/);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I will try this solution. But I was half way through the other solution that was posted. And I have made the EDIT. Can you see once. I am stuck at one place.

Comment: I want to hit the INDEX function which takes the argument. Not the empty one.

Comment: Is `GetAvailableLocationsFor` in the same controller as `Index`?

Comment: Nope. `GetAvailableLocationsFor` is in `settingsController` And in home controller I have two action with name as Index. I have added the Edit of  return statement of `GetAvailableLocationsFor `

Comment: So, homecontroller has two Index Action.

Comment: @Unbreakable Can I ask why you want to go to the HttpPost method?  Typically those methods are for saving data to a database or something like that.. why can't you just put the same parameters in the HttpGet?  Honestly this is making me think that you need to rethink the structure of this.

Comment: Ok, here is the thing. I have website which has two section on UI. left side is for the settings where you can change colour and all. Right side is for the preview. The Index with the parameter is called when the preview needs to be updated. so that the admin can see the settings change on the fly. Where as the empty index is called when the actual configured website is opened.

Comment: If you want me to take Httppost out of the index Action I will take it out. But after that will I be able to hit that index with parameter one?

Comment: More like wordpress website with configure on the left and preview on the right.

Comment: In order to see the settings change on the real time I need the Index with the parameter to get hit. it will update the preview window on the right

Answer (score 0):

For your question 
**After the solution suggested "use TempData " But the problem is I have two index action in my controller. I want the SECOND Index Action to get hit. But the first one is getting hit** what you can do is based on some data which you can set in TempData you can call `return Index(data)` from your first index method, you can get **data** through Tempdata or some other variable. This will call you second index method through first index method.

Comment: I added this ` [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]` on the top of my parameterized index Action which I wanted to hit. And it's working. Thank you so much for your suggestion though..