# How to call nested ajax call and send object data to controller in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two controller

1. Settings Controller

   Action - GetAvailableLocationsFor
2. HomeController

   Action - Index

Steps I want to acheive

1. Make ajax call to `GetAvailableLocationsFor` and then get the object data from success call back. No view is required for this Action.
2. Now with the object data received make another ajax call to Index Action in HOMECONTROLLER and pass the object there.

Below is what I could achieve.

**HomeController - GetAvailableLocationsFor**

```
public ActionResult GetAvailableLocationsFor(int accountId, int groupId)
        {
            FullConfigMV configData = SetLoader.GetSettings(accountId, groupId);
           return // HOW TO RETURN configData from Here to first ajax call
}
```

**HomeController - Index Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FullConfigMV data)
{
  //SECOND AJAX CALL SHOULD COME HERE
}
```

**Nested Ajax call**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#tan").change(function()
        {
            alert(this.value);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Settings/GetAvailableLocationsFor',
                data: { accountId: 28462, groupId: 35},
                success: function (data) { // data should represent configObj

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Home/Index',
                        data: // WHAT TO WRITE HERE,
                        success: function (data) {
                            //WHATEVER
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            DisplayError('Failed to load the data.');
                        }
                    });

                },
                error: function () {
                    DisplayError('Failed to load the data.');
                }
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi do you actually need a ajax call in second time? I mean you can use Url.Action ('','') after success callback with all required data .

Comment: `return Json(configData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and `data: data` (but this could simply be done using one ajax call to one method - its not clear why you want 2 methods)

Comment: @YashveerSingh: can you kindly guide me how to achieve that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thank you for your response. I have some logic in `GetAvailableLocationsFor` and the Index sometimes needs to be called independent of the logic which is in `GetAvailableLocationsFor`

Comment: @StephenMuecke In certain situation I want just the Index logic to be called. And in certain situation I want the logic of `GetAvailableLocationsFor ` to be called and then the index should be called.

Comment: Why not send an additional parameter indicating if the 'other' logic needs to be executed and call a private method/service in the `GetAvailableLocationsFor ()` method? But see my first comment for the 2 changes you need to make

Comment: The answer below is deleted by the poster. :(

Comment: @Unbreakable I'm not sure if you have a service layer but it sounds like this common logic might be better off living in a common service layer. Or possibly some Utility class in your app layer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  if I take out [httpost] will that help. Will I be able to pass value then?

Comment: But nothing in your code is conditionally calling the `Index()` method - it will always be called

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to return a redirect in your `GetAvailableLocationsFor` action

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", configData)`

Then in your ajax success instead of the second ajax call. Just handle whatever gets returned by Home/Index.

Comment: You cannot redirect to a POST :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are absolutely correct. I missed the httppost attribute.

Comment: If I take the httppost attribute then this code will work right?

Comment: @Unbreakable it depends on what else is calling that action. It might be better to allow both httppost and httpget. For example if you have a form that is submitting to home/index and you don't explicitly tell it to submit via GET it will default to POST and fail if you remove that attribute.

Comment: So, I have put both httpost and httpget. Now Can I use your code and get the data at Index Action?

Comment: @Unbreakable as the return statement for you GetAvailableLocationsFor action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133387/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-keith-abramo).

Answer (score 0):

Return `JSON` data from `GetAvailableLocationsFor` method. After in second ajax call you can send data like below:

```
data: JSON.parse(response),
```

this will get data in your parameter in `Index` method